Handling Certificate Revocation and Renewal on Android from device
I have successfully written code in Android to enroll with a CA and obtain certificates using the jscep library. So far, I have successfully enrolled and obtained certificates from NDES, EJBCA, and Digicert SCEP servers.
Now, I need to handle certificate revocation and renewal. Here is what I understand and where I need help:
Renewal:
For certificate renewal, my understanding is that I can simply re-enroll with SCEP to get a fresh certificate. Is this the correct approach, or is there a more standard method to handle certificate renewal?
Revocation:
Since jscep does not support certificate revocation, I am looking for alternative methods to handle this. Specifically:
How can I initiate a certificate revocation request from the device side?
Is it possible to send an HTTP PUT request or any other type of request to revoke a certificate? If so, what should the request look like?
Any guidance, sample code, or references on handling certificate revocation and renewal from NDES/EJBCA server in an Android environment would be greatly appreciated.

Certificate renewal with SCEP is done with the RenewalReq message.
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8894#name-certificate-enrolment-renew
SCEP does not support a certificate revocation message, https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8894#name-certificate-revocation
Other protocols like CMP support revocation. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4210#section-5.3.9
In general SCEP is a quite outdated protocol. There is no telling if that will be updated for post-quantum algorithms, that would likely require a substantial rewrite of SCEP.
